# How to select distinct values for two and return all columns?

Tags: sql, oracle, distinct, distinct-values

I want to select distinct values from two columns.

Example data:

```
ID TITLE SOURCE TARGET
1  asd   12      2
2  asd1  123     125
3  asd1  123     56  
4  asd2  123     125
5  asd3  164     146
```

I want to get distinct data for source and target columns ID - 2 and ID - 4 are duplicates.

```
ID TITLE SOURCE TARGET
1  asd   12      2
2  asd1  123     125
3  asd1  123     56  
5  asd3  164     146
```

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the distinct values, use `select distinct`:

```
select distinct source, target
from example t;
```

If you want the rows where the source/target only appears on one row, then one method uses window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by source, target) as cnt
      from example t
     ) t
where cnt = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for prompt response, I want to select all column where the source/target only appears on one row. I change "from t" to my real table name but, I got: ORA-00904: "T": invalid identifier

Comment: Don't change `t` to your real name, but `example`.

Comment: @Goku . . . I edited the answer using `example` as the name of your table.

Comment: Why I got two negative votes on this question?

Comment: @Goku . . . I have no idea.  There seem to be plenty of Stack Overflow users who like to downvote without specifying why.  Just consider it a badge of honor.